# Why won't my tableview cell load when I run this app?

Tags: swift, xcode

In this simple [project](https://github.com/jasonyunjoonpark/techfetcher)! I am using a tableview and trying to display one cell but when I run the app it doesn't show the one cell I want it to. I don't know what I did wrong. I think it has something to do with the constraints. I'm lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate / data source and then reload the tableview within view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I edited it, you needed to set the delegate and data source

Comment: thanks it worked but i get a constraint error im not sure if that's okay or if i should try to fix the constraint error